# Where did Flask-Admin's `hide_backrefs` option go? How to display backrefs in admin list view?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

Previous version of Flask-Admin had a `hide_backrefs` option which could be set to `False` if you wanted to show them in the admin view.

The current version seems to have it no longer. Does it go by some other name? If I want to display backreferences in the admin list view, is there a better solution than just manually setting `columns_list`?

Answer (score 2):

This option was removed because you can explicitly add `id` field to the create and edit forms.